# How to keep Windows print spooler running?

Tags: windows-vista, printing

It crashes within around 5 seconds of launching on a Windows Vista x64 box (patches current).  No changes to the machine recently, just suddenly started happening in the middle of a bunch of prints.  Obviously unable to print (or even see the printers in the control panel) once it's crashed.  It just throws a generic error about needing to stop, nothing useful gets logged (at least not that I've found).  Reboot doesn't change anything.  Has anyone else run across this and found a way to fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've seen something similar happen when there's a corrupt print job in one of your queues have a look in C:\WINDOWS\System32\spool\PRINTERS and delete any files that are in there then try restarting the print server.

Answer (score 0):

It sound like a corrupt printer driver. I would suggest removing the printer completely, rebooting and then seeing if the spooler stays running. Then re-install the printer with a generic driver, not the original, and see if that works.

The spooler is fairly straight forward, and apart from drivers not much else can crash it.

Answer (score 0):

To add to Diago's suggestion, the drivers can be found here:

```
C:\windows\system32\spool\drivers
```

You will want to delete the ones in the x64 and w32x86 folders. Using a 32-bit driver on a 64-bit system can cause a lot of headaches but a 64-bit driver could easily be at fault for this. After rebooting, if the crashing stops, reinstall your printer drivers 1 at a time so you can pinpoint the problem if it happens again.